# Bot framework Unable to use with Skype For Business

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

I've built a Bot using C#. I tested it using the emulator, web chat, direct line and Skype, and it's working as expected.
I followed the steps to register the bot with skype for business, I waited more than 24 hours to see what's happen.
So far, I can see the Bot as a contact, however, when I try to send a message, the error

> "Error happened in Skype for business when reaching bot service. We
>   saved this conversation. You'll see it soon in the Conversations tab
>   in Skype for Business and in the Conversation History folder in
>   Outlook."

Looking for some logs or something, I collected some info, that I'm sharing here.

Analytics from BOT that proves that it's reaching it:
[image: Analytics]

The Log for SFB channel said: "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code NotFound"

It's look that the Bot endpoint is not available. When I registered it in SFB, I've been using NGROK (to run agains my machine), but later I've change it to a azure site.

"Old" endpoint is used yet today:
[image: endpoint]

So, all I can guess is that Bot End Point was "registered" at the moment that I made the registration of my Bot in SFB, and now it's not possible to change it.

Does it make sense to anyone of you?

My problem seems to be kind of similar to [Bot Framework - An error while sending a message from Skype for Business](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962518/bot-framework-an-error-while-sending-a-message-from-skype-for-business)

Adrián

Comment: Thanks for the edition Nicolás! As you can see, my written english is not the best.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm sure the problem with the bot was the endpoint registration. I found a powershell script that update the endpoint. 
I Opened Windows PowerShell as Administrator and run the ff scripts:

```
Import-PSSession (New-CsOnlineSession -Credential (Get-Credential))
Set-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint -Uri sip:username@yourdomain.com
```

Obviously, I changed `username@yourdomain.com` with my own.
Then, after waiting 8 hours (or so), I was able to communicate with the bot, using SFB as channel.

[Bot running as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsIS9.png)

I hope this can be useful for others.